# How to replace the word which is not placed between a pattern using Oracle REGEXP and not the same word inside the pattern?

Tags: sql, oracle, pattern-matching, regexp-replace, regexp-like

I am trying to replace the word "group" when it's not between the pattern `<a href` and `a>` with "group1" . Below query replaces "group" inside the desired pattern. How to replace the word which is just outside the pattern?

```
with t as (
    select '<a href Part of the technical Network Group www.tech.com/sites/ hh a> group' as text from dual
    union all select '<a href mean www.tech.technical Network a>' as text from dual
    union all select 'www.tech.tech///technical <a href Network Group a>' as text from dual)
select regexp_replace(text,'group','group1',1,0,'i')
from t
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(text,'<a href.*group.*a>','i')
```

The expected output for the first row is (the word "group" appears inside and outside the pattern). The expectation is to just replace the one which is outside)

```
<a href Part of the technical Network group www.tech.com/sites/ hh a> group1
```

Comment: Please show us the exact output you expect here.

Comment: In general, to figure out whether `group` occurs inside or outside an anchor, or any other, HTML tag, is beyond the ability of regex alone (it is _certainly_ beyond the regex flavor running inside Oracle).  So, I recommend that you export your HTML content from Oracle to a tool more suitable for this type of work, such as Java or C#.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, Tim. I will check for more options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be remiss if I did not point everyone reading this to the definitive post on parsing HTML with regex's:
[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Thanks, Gary. This is helpful.